# Name for simple character encoding (where '0' is 0x00; 'A' is 0x0A)?

Tags: encodings

Some old games have a very simple text encoding in which:

```
0x00 = '0'
0x01 = '1'
...
0x09 = '9'
0x0A = 'A'
0x0B = 'B'
0x0C = 'C'
...
0x22 = 'Y'
0x23 = 'Z'
...
0xFF = string terminator
```

I figure this encoding must be pretty common due to its extreme simplicity so I was wondering if there's a correct/de facto name for it.

Comment: "Minimal", perhaps. Since available memory is usually small, there is no reason to include bitmaps for all that #%£?! crap, and if you don't include them, the encoding can be kept tight and simple as well to have a 1:1 relation with the bitmaps.

Comment: 0xFF will not be the terminator as that requires 8 bits, and the whole point to remapping the ASCII to a small space is to them use some form of bit stuffing. packing the character into 6 bit allows for each 4 characters to use 3 byes.